# How to retrieve values with apostrophes from Sqlite

Tags: python, sql, quotes

I have a Sqlite3 table that I am trying to access with Python. All is working well except one table column where the value contains an apostrophe (eg. George's).

I have worked out the SQL

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = '" + value1 + "' and column2 = '" + value2 + "'"`

but a syntax error results when `value2 = George's`.

What is the correct Python syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this, is to use placeholders in your query to really avoid problems with [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

here's a simple example:

**code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3

dbc = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c   = dbc.cursor()

name  = "george's"
query = "select * from names where name = ?"

c.execute(query, (name,))

for row in c.fetchall():
    print row
```

**which outputs a tuple containing the row from the DB:**

```
(1, u"george's")
```

**the sqlite3 table:**

```
sqlite> .schema names
CREATE TABLE names(id integer primary key asc, name char);

sqlite> select * from names;
1|george's
2|dave
3|george
```

Comment: Placeholders were not a concern since the db is local but it does resolve the syntax issue...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the backslash to escape the apostrophe.  For example:

```
select * from tablename where columnname='George\'s'
```

Comment: escaping with backslashes is, as far as I know, MySQL only; ANSI sql uses `'`'s as the escape character.

Comment: The apostrophe is not easily accessible since it is the part of the value obtained from another db. value2 = "George's"

Comment: It sounds like you are storing the value obtained from the other db in a python variable, then reusing this value again in a second query.  And, the quotes must be escaped in the second query.  In this case, a search and replace might help:

value2=value2.replace("'","\'")

Answer (score 1):

first: obligitory link: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

To save yourself from this sort of thing, you should be using placeholders.  This is a python question, so python answer:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select ?", ['this contains quotes: "\'"']).fetchall()
[(u'this contains quotes: "\'"',)]
```

For non-dynamic portions of your query, though, the 'escape' mechanism is to double up quotes:

```
>>> cur.execute("select ''''").fetchall()
[(u"'",)]
```

`?` is the placeholder for sqlite, and many others, But the correct placeholder may be different for the database you are actually using.  Other common syntax is `:param` (PostgreSQL) and `%s` (MySQL)

Comment: being a python newby, this is a little complex for me...thanks.